# Why is the battery usage graph so useless?

Tags: battery-life, battery-history

Is it just my phone (Nexus 5, 5.1) or did the battery usage graph become useless in Lollipop?

I've attached a graph from today that, at first (and second) glance, makes no sense at all. This is after about an hour of sitting idle with the screen off.

[image: a graph from today]

If someone could please explain what's going on I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: What happened to the other 97% of usage?

Comment: Also, I did ask for someone to explain what's happening. So if you know what's being shared in the image you should be able to provide an answer, correct?

Comment: The percentages do not refer to actual battery use, e. g. on your device, those 1% marks don't mean that specific application has used the 1% of the battery.

Comment: Yes. It has become rather useless. You can't know how many hours passed since you unplugged it, and now the percentages do not add up to 100% (as they should in any rational universe)

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106921/battery-percentages-per-app-nowhere-near-total