# Why don't the percentages on the battery chart add up to anywhere near 100%?

Tags: cyanogenmod, battery-life, oneplus-one

I'm trying to figure out what's using my battery life by looking at the battery page in Settings. (I don't know if this screen is Cyanogen specific, or a stock Android feature.) Here's a recent screenshot of that page:

[image: Battery usage chart]

Transcript:

> **Current battery level: 67%**
>
> Use since last full charge:
>
> - Android System: 3%
> - Screen: 2%
> - Cell Standby: 2%
> - Ironclad Tactics: 2%
> - Google App: 1%
> - Android OS: 1%
> - Google Play Services: 1%

(It may not be clear from the screenshot, but that's the end of the list: there's nothing off-screen.) I don't know whether those percentages are supposed to add up to 100% (logical) or to 33% (the amount of battery used so far), but either way, they actually add up to 12%. No amount of rounding error can explain that. At best, 2/3 of my battery usage is totally unaccounted for.

This is a common occurrence. I have another screenshot where my battery level is 18%, but the sum of all the used apps is only 44%.

What could be using up so much battery that wouldn't show on this list? Or alternately, could some battery usage pattern could cause this screen to grossly underestimate usage of a particular app? Or could a faulty battery, that drains more quickly than it should for a given load, cause this?

Comment: We already had this here: [Battery percentages per app nowhere near total](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/106921/16575): 1) the list is incomplete (everything below a threshold (1%?) won't appear), 2) values are not "accurate" but "rounded".

Comment: Izzy, I don't see how that's relevant to my situation. Rounding errors and a few more apps with <1% usage might add a few percent, but more than half of my battery usage is unaccounted for. Based on the linked post, I would need over 75 extra apps, all with just barely under 1% battery usage, to explain the difference! (Or 150 apps with an average of 0.5% each, or 300 apps with an average 0.25% each... it seems very unlikely.)

Comment: Also consider that some stuff there is no app (screen, Android OS, etc.), plus if that's really all in your screenshot ("nothing off screen", as you've put it), it's definitely incomplete. The linked post contains all we currently know about that issue; but feel free to [edit] your question with a link to that one plus an explanation what makes your question different (or the other not fully apply), to have it re-opened.

Comment: I've seen the same but even worse.  Battery nearly empty and only a cumulative total of 6% usage reported in chart.  Would be nice if we understood if there's ways apps might consume power without android detecting it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have last charged your device, its displaying the ratio [usage time/time since charged] * 100 of that service
It might be that you didnt use any service and the screen was off most of the time
If you use many apps simultaneously (consider using 4 apps at a time) using these all the time till your phone gets discharged will show the time for these apps to be 100% but if you add these %ages for all the apps it will be greater than 100